# Access in a static way or via parameter?

Tags: java, android, static

```
public class RootActivity extends Activity
{
    static LiLa superLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        main();
        setContentView(superLayout);
    }

    private void main()
    {
        // LiLa is a class which extends LinearLayout
        superLayout = new LiLa(this);

        //DownloadData is an AsyncTask
        DownloadData mDownloadData = new DownloadData(this);
        mDownloadData.execute();
    }
}
```

So the AsyncTask change some parts of the superLayout, for now in the AsyncTak, I do :

```
RootActivity.superLayout.tv.setText("hello");
```

Would it be better to change :

```
static LiLa superLayout;
```

to

```
LiLa superLayout;
```

and :

```
DownloadData mDownloadData = new DownloadData(this);
```

to

```
DownloadData mDownloadData = new DownloadData(this, superLayout);
```

So that it would be possible to do in the AsyncTask :

```
superLayout.tv.setText("hello");
```

So question is : is it better to access this kind of parameters (TextView tv for example) or a method to change this TextView through static way or via parameter ?

Thanks for reading me.

**EDIT : btw in my code it is a bit more messy it could be more like**

```
RootActivity.superLayout.class1.class2.tv.setText("hello");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to avoid using a `static` in this case, and if that means that you need to pass the value as a parameter, that's fine too.  (Statics are not O-O, and are generally a bad idea in an O-O design.  They also present problems in unit testing.)

It is also generally a good idea to declare all instance variables and provide getter and/or setter methods if that is required.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C. Better for performance, readability, OOP's paradigm ? I am almost convince about readability, but I have no clue about performance.

Comment: A half decent JIT compiler will inline typical getters and setters, so there should be no performance difference.  (And if there is, it will most likely be so small as to be irrelevant.)  The real advantages of using getters and setters are improving abstraction / reducing dependencies on implementation details, and facilitating the development of subclasses at some point in the future.  (A getter / setter can be overridden, but an exposed field cannot.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think static access to a layout is the best way of doing it.

A better solution would be to save the layout as a private variable and then add your `AsyncTask` as an inner class of your activity:

```
public class RootActivity extends Activity
{
    private LiLa superLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        main();
        setContentView(superLayout);
    }

    private void main()
    {
        // LiLa is a class which extends LinearLayout
        superLayout = new LiLa(this);

        //DownloadData is an AsyncTask
        new DownloadData().execute();
    }

    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<..., ..., ...> {
       //You can reference the variable superLayout here.
       //If you need the context, use RootActivity.this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kasper Moerch. I am not a big fan of inner class, I more like "spartan" classes... anyway it's just my personnal taste.  Same question : I see the obvious advantage what about performance is it also relevant ?

Answer (score 1):

I think **access view in parameter is better way**. SO we don't have to make any static reference for the class or activity.

Answer (score 1):

Read the "A public static field/method" part of this link:

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3

I hope this will help.

Comment: I also thinks that using "static" is not the better way but I have found something different on this link.